# How to create a public share-link for private resources in firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I created a simple database in firebase which backs up data from an android application and has the following structure:

```
-item
  -owner_id
  -property1
  -property2
  ...
  -subitem
    -more properties
```

And tht's already it. But now I want to add the option to create a link like you can do it in google drive or dropbox, that allows everyone with the link to see the data. (With no login required).

So I thought, I'd create a password/key for every item, which would be included in the link and allows users to access the item, even when not signed in. But I struggle to find a solution that makes this possible **with firebase's access rules**, since I don't want to have every item publicly readable.
Are there any options to do this **without custom tokens** created by a separate server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two fairly straightforward approaches here:

1. Set up an endpoint that handles the requirement.
2. Handle the requirement through the REST API of the Firebase Database.

#### Set up an endpoint that handles the requirement

The first approach requires that you set up a server or implement a Cloud Functions HTTPS endpoint that takes the user request, validates the password/key from the link and then look up and returns the data if all checks out.

This seems quite straightforward, but it does mean that you're adding server-side code, which I never like. That's why I always look for an approach that can stay within just the Firebase Database.

#### Handle the requirement through the REST API of the Firebase Database.

The Firebase Realtime Database has a REST API, where you can directly access the data at a specific point. E.g. `https://yours.firebaseio.com/items/item1.json` This REST API still follows the security rules that you have for your database, so you'll either need to [authenticate the URL with an access token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#generate_an_access_token), or make it publicly accessible. Since generating tokens is rather involved, I'm going for the latter here.

The thing to realize is that we can't pass a email/password/token to the REST API in this case. But what we can instead do is putting the data at an unguessable path. So pretty much instead of `https://yours.firebaseio.com/items/item1.json?token=verysecrettoken` we'll use `https://yours.firebaseio.com/public/verysecrettoken/item1.json`. In the latter I've put the public data under a top-level `public` node, which makes it easier to secure. Just be sure to not make the entire `/public` node readable because then someone could `https://yours.firebaseio.com/public.json` to get it all. More likely you'll do something like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "public": {
      "$secret": {
        ".read": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this structure only somebody who knows a valid `$secret` value, can read the corresponding data.

Comment: Ah I see, first of all thank you very much for this extensive response. I thought of the "unguessable path" thing too, but I was unaware that I could make a higher level path private, to prevent users from just looking at all subdirectories! Thank you!